# Creating a list from CSV value in Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In a flask template, I'd like to loop over my values which is a comma separated range of values. So in my template, I'd like to do something like:

```
{% for tag in list(myparent.my_tags) %}

{{tag}}

{% endfor %}
```

I can see `list` in the documents, but I don't see how to use it. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/

The value of `my_tags` is abc, def, ghi,... and the aim to loop over each group in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja2's `split` function should work.

```
{% for tag in myparent.my_tags.split(',') %}

{{ tag }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't see split in the documentation, thanks a lot!